# DataPump Export ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Tags: oracle, datapump

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.1.0 64bit Production

DataPump Export command:

```
EXPDP.EXE SCHEMA1/SCHEMA1PASS@ORCL DIRECTORY=exp_dir1 DUMPFILE=SCHEMA1.dmp LOGFILE=SCHEMA1.LOG EXCLUDE=GRANT FULL=N REUSE_DUMPFILES=Y FLASHBACK_TIME=SYSTIMESTAMP COMPRESSION=ALL
```

Log shows an error about one table. All other are exported succesfully.

`SCHEMA1.LOG` error lines:

```
ORA-31693: Table data object "SCHEMA1"."TABLE1" failed to load/unload and is 
           being skipped dua to error
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

The following day another export was fine, but at the next export that error appeared again and is shown ever since.

Is there a way to find which records or fields caused the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There might a problem with your "SCHEMA1"."TABLE1". Please post TABLE1 so we can see what might be the problem.

Comment: I am not sure but try without `FLASHBACK_TIME=SYSTIMESTAMP` to just test it